# Trunc sytax problem

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

If any one could help me with the syntax issues which I am facing here.

```
sqlshipped := ' and a.ORDS_COMPLETED_DATE between '
            ||shippedfrom
            ||' and trunc('
            ||shippedto
            ||' + 1) ';
```

I am appending this to other stings to frame my query. Before this line everything works fine and as expected. The `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` for this statement is

```
and a.ORDS_COMPLETED_DATE between 20.06.07 and trunc(23.06.07 + 1)
```

The error which I get now is

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

It would be of great help if some one can correct . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to print the resulting dynamic query string out, then edit it into your question.

Comment: edited the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove redundant parentheses surrounding BETWEEN clause.
After all I think the best solution would be:

```
sqlshipped := ' select * from TEST_TABLE a where 
a.ORDS_COMPLETED_DATE between :1 and  trunc(:2 + 1) ';   
execute immediate sqlshipped using shippedfrom, shippedto;
```

This is most efficient, because when using binding query need not to be parsed at each execution.
Please read more at: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Comment: If they are redundant why will the change solve anything?

Comment: I changed the line as you stated above. After putting DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. The output I am getting for this line is   ' and a.ORDS_COMPLETED_DATE between 20.06.07 and trunc(23.06.07 + 1)'. The error now is 'ORA-00905: missing keyword' for the same line

Comment: you're right, I hurried up. I fixed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to the above post.

```
sqlshipped :=' and a.ORDS_COMPLETED_DATE between TO_DATE('
            ||''''
            ||shippedfrom
            ||''''
            ||',''DD-MM-YY'''
            || ')and TRUNC(TO_DATE('
            ||''''
            ||shippedto
            ||''''
            ||',''DD-MM-YY'''
            ||') + 1) ';
```